# Kotlin changing value with button click

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have tried to make a button that subtracts from the "SavingsAccount" and adds to the "MainAccount" but sadly when i click the "Transfer" button nothing happens :( any help would be appreciated.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val savingsAccount = BankAccount(name = "uzzi", amount = 50, accountType = "SAVING")
        val mainAccount = BankAccount(name = "uzzi", amount = 100, accountType = "MAIN")

        var users = mutableListOf(savingsAccount, mainAccount)

        textView3.text = ""
        for (user in users){
            textView3.append("${user.name} ${user.amount} ${user.accountType}\n")
            }

        var Convert = findViewById<Button>(R.id.transfer_Saving)
        transfer_Saving.setOnClickListener{
            users[0].subtractAmount(50)
            users[1].addAmount(50)

       }
        }
    }
```

this a second kotlin file

```
package com.example.oboppgave4344 
 class BankAccount (var name: String, var amount: Int, var accountType: String){
 fun subtractAmount(subtract: Int) = amount - subtract
 fun addAmount(add: Int) = amount + add
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to test the functionality by directly keeping the code there and ones it works you could move it up into a function.

Answer (score 2):

Your `subtractAmount` and `addAmount` functions aren't actually changing the values in your `BankAccount` class, they're just calculating a result (and returning it).

You want to do something like

```
fun subtractAmount(subtract: Int) {
    amount = amount - subtract
}
```

which you can shorten to `amount -= subtract` if you like!

Comment: I did this but on the app it still does not change the value in the textview. Also Thanks

Comment: You need to update the textview yourself, it's not smart like that! The part where you clear the textview and add all the ``users`` info, pull that out into a separate function called ``displayAccounts`` or something. Then you can call it again from your ``onClickListener`` after you've updated the accounts, so it can refresh the display

Comment: Thanks, for the help I got that working. But, how would i change the subtract and addition into a editText. So, the button itself would use a user input to subtract that amount from the SAVINGS and add that amount to Main.

Comment: You'd need to read the contents of the ``EditText`` and parse it into a number (like with ``String.toInt()``), and use the result in your ``subtract`` and ``add`` calls. I'd put that parsing stuff into its own function too, it's cleaner and you can make it more complex later if you need to. You can return ``null`` from the function if the ``EditText`` couldn't be parsed as a valid number (there's a ``toIntOrNull`` function as well) and then your click listener code can decide what to do if it gets a null, like showing an error message